# css - Displaying images with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to display a number of images horizontally inside of a fixed-width div.  I would like to use a horizontal scroll bar to display the images which do not fit inside the div.

However, the images are displaying vertically, rather than horizontally.  Is there a way to force them to display side-by-side?

```
div#event {
width: 150px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

div#event ul { list-style: none; }

div#event img {
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

<div id="lasteventimg">
<ul><li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to display the list items inline or float them and give the ul a very large width to avoid items moving to the next line:

```
ul {
  width: 10000px;    // for example
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  float: left:
  // or
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: hey I'm having the same problem, but i'm not using any lists- I just have images being added to a horizontal div (via javascript) I am using float:left, and overflow-x:scroll,

Answer (score 12):

Correct code for arbitrary number of images, if you don't know ul width:

```
#lasteventimg {width:150px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;}
ul {list-style:none; display:block;white-space:nowrap;}
li {width: 100px;display:inline;}


<div id="lasteventimg">
<ul>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image4.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image5.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this does work, whenever inline elements encounter a newline, the browser inserts white space between the inline elements.  There is no way via CSS to get rid of it reliably across browsers.  You'll have to either do the "Jesus Fish" hack ( <li>stuff</li><[new line]li>stuff ) or eliminate the line break between the tags ( <li></li> )

Comment: @mrbinky3000: Sticking comments between the lines to keep line breaks works too (`</li><!--\n--><li>`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
div#lasteventimg ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

To make sure the `li` elements aren't rendered as block elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you need to change your styles from `#event` to `#lasteventimg`. Then, if you set the `width` of the `ul` to be wide enough to accommodate all the images, you should see the behavior that you're trying to get:

```
div#lasteventimg {
width: 150px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

div#lasteventimg ul { list-style: none; width: 300px; }

div#lasteventimg img {
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

<div id="lasteventimg">
<ul><li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="./gfx/gallery/image3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your list, so the elements are rendered horizontally rather then the default vertical.

```
#imagelist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
ul
{
   width: 10000px; 
   white-space: nowrap;
}

li 
{
   display: block;
   float:left;
}
```